# looking for a bitmap implementation API in linux C

Tags: c, linux, api, bitmap

I want a bitmap API in linux C.

I need 2^18 bits, so it needs 32KB memory. and I will frequently set and unset bits in the bitmap.

so basically I need APIs like:

```
set_bitmap(int i)  // it sets the i-th bit to 1 in the bitmap
unset_bitmap(int i) // it sets the i-th bit to 0 in the bitmap
bitmap_t create_bitmap(int n) // it creates a bitmap of size n, like n=2^18
```

are there any source code or similar source codes?

thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement a bitset in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372515/how-to-implement-a-bitset-in-c)

Comment: [It is “code”, not “codes”!](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20455/is-it-wrong-to-use-the-word-codes-in-a-programming-context)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This isn't difficult.

```
typedef unsigned char* bitmap_t;

void set_bitmap(bitmap_t b, int i) {
    b[i / 8] |= 1 << (i & 7);
}

void unset_bitmap(bitmap_t b, int i) {
    b[i / 8] &= ~(1 << (i & 7));
}

void get_bitmap(bitmap_t b, int i) {
    return b[i / 8] & (1 << (i & 7)) ? 1 : 0;
}

bitmap_t create_bitmap(int n) {
    return malloc((n + 7) / 8);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be a mistake in the other answer in function `get_bitmap`. The bit detection should be done like this:

```
b[i / 8] & (1 << (i & 7))
```

The whole corrected code is then:

```
typedef unsigned char* bitmap_t;

void set_bitmap(bitmap_t b, int i) {
    b[i / 8] |= 1 << (i & 7);
}

void unset_bitmap(bitmap_t b, int i) {
    b[i / 8] &= ~(1 << (i & 7));
}

int get_bitmap(bitmap_t b, int i) {
    return b[i / 8] & (1 << (i & 7)) ? 1 : 0;
}

bitmap_t create_bitmap(int n) {
    return malloc((n + 7) / 8);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// C++ API
//
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

using namespace std;

class BitSet
{
    public:
        BitSet(int n); 
        ~BitSet();
        bool setBit(int index);
        bool unsetBit(int index);
        char getBit(int index);
        void printBits();

    private:
        unsigned char* m_buffer;
        int m_range;
};

BitSet::BitSet(int n)
{
    m_buffer = (unsigned char*) malloc((n+7)/8);
    assert(m_buffer);
    for (int ii = 0; ii < n; ii++) {
        m_buffer[ii] = 0x00;
    }   
    m_range = n;
}

BitSet::~BitSet()
{
    if (m_buffer) {
        free(m_buffer);
    }   
}

bool
BitSet::setBit(int index)
{
    if (index < 0 || index >= m_range) {
        return false;
    }   

    m_buffer[index/8] = m_buffer[index/8] | ((0x01 << (index%8)));
    return true;
}

bool
BitSet::unsetBit(int index)
{
    if (index < 0 || index >= m_range) {
        return false;
    }   

    m_buffer[index/8] &= ~(0x01 << (index%8));
    return true;
}

char
BitSet::getBit(int index)
{
    if (index < 0 || index >= m_range) {
        return false;
    }

    return (m_buffer[index/8] & (0x01 << (index%8))) ? 0x01 : 0x00;
}

void
BitSet::printBits()
{
    for (int ii = 0; ii < m_range/8; ii++) {
        cout<<"'"<<std::hex<<int(m_buffer[ii])<<"'";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```