# Implement existing network interface defining bit-fields with respect to endianess in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, endianness, bit-fields

I am current developing a C++11 library for an **existing** network remote
control interface described in an Interface Control Document (ICD).

The interface is based on TCP/IPv4 and uses *Network Byte Order* (aka *Big
Endian*).

**Requirement:** The library shall be developed **cross-platform**.

*Note:* I want to develop a solution **without** (ab)using the preprocessor.

After a short research on the WWW I discovered [Boost.Endian](http://boost.org/libs/endian) which solves
problems related to endianess of multi-byte data types. My approach is as
follows:

1. Serialize the (multi-)byte data types to a stream via
   [std::basic_ostream::write](http://boost.org/libs/endian), more precisely via
   `os.write(reinterpret_cast<char const *>(&kData), sizeof(kData))`.
2. Convert the `std::basic_ostream` to a `std::vector<std::uint8_t>`.
3. Send the `std::vector<std::uint8_t>` via [Boost.Asio](http://boost.org/libs/boost_asio) over the network.

So far so good. Everything seems to work as intended and the solution should be
platform independent.

Now comes the tricky part: The ICD describes messages consisting of multiple
words and a word consists of 8 bits. A message can contain multiple fields and a
field does not have to be byte-aligned, which means that one word can contain
multiple fields.

*Example:* Consider the following message format (the message body starts at
word 10):

```
Word | Bit(s) | Name
-----|--------|----------
 10  |  0-2   |  a
 10  |   3    |  b
 10  |   4    |  c
 10  |   5    |  d
 10  |   6    |  e
 10  |   7    |  RESERVED
 11  |   16   |  f
```

and so on...

So now I need a solution to be able to model and serialize a bit-based interface.

I have looked at the following approaches so far:

1. [*Bit field*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field)
2. [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)
3. [`boost::dynamic_bitset`](http://boost.org/libs/dynamic_bitset)

   - [1](http://boost.org/libs/endian) is not cross-platform (compiler dependent).
   - [2](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) and [3](http://boost.org/libs/boost_asio) do seem to work with *Native Byte Order* (i.e. *Little Endian* on
     my machine) only, so the following example using `boost::dynamic_bitset` does not
     work for my scenario:

*Code*:

```
// Using a arithmetic type from the `boost::endian` namespace does not work.
using Byte = std::uint8_t;
using BitSet = boost::dynamic_bitset<Byte>;
BitSet bitSetForA{3, 1};
BitSet bitSetForB{1};
// [...]
BitSet bitSetForF{16, 0x400}; // 1024
```

So, the 1024 in the example above is always serialized to `00 04` instead of
  `04 00` on my machine.

I really do not know what's the most pragmatic approach to solve my problem.
Maybe you can guide me into the correct direction.

In conclusion I do need a recipe to implement an existing network interface defining bit
fields in a platform-independent way with respect to the native byte order of
the machine the library has been compiled on.

Comment: take a look at good old c alternatives http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372515/how-to-implement-a-bitset-in-c

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I am looking for a generic solution which supports multiple lengths (e.g. uint8, uint16, uint32, uint64) and does not required lots of hand-made code. I want to define each message field, concat them and convert them to a byte vector with respect to the correct endianess.

Answer (score 0):

Someone recently kindly pointed me to a [nice article about endianness](http://commandcenter.blogspot.de/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html) from which I took inspiration.

`std::bitset` has a `to_ulong` method that can be used to return the integer representation of the bitfield (endian independent), and the following code will print your output in the correct order:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
  std::bitset<16> flags;
  flags[10] = true;
  unsigned long rawflags = flags.to_ulong();
  std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << std::hex
            << (rawflags & 0x0FF) // little byte in the beginning                                                     
            << std::setw(2)
            << ((rawflags>>8) & 0x0FF) // big byte in the end                                                         
            << std::endl;
}
```

Note that no solution using bit fields will easily work in this case, since also the bits will be swapped on little endian machines!

e.g. in a structure like this:

```
struct bits {
  unsigned char first_bit:1;
  unsigned char rest:7;
};
union {
  bits b;
  unsigned char raw;
};
```

Setting b.fist_bit to 1 will result in a raw value of 1 or 128 depending on the endianness!

HTH