# What is the fastest way to organize data in C?

Tags: c, performance, sorting, memory-management, kernel

I need to keep track of **a lot** of boolean-esque data in C. I'm writing a toy kernel and need to store data on whether a certain memory address is **used** or **free**. Because of this, I need to store and traverse through this data in the fastest, most efficient way possible. Since I am writing the kernel from scratch I **cannot use the C Standard Library.** What's the best, fastest, most efficient way to organize, traverse through and modify a large series of boolean-esque data without using the C Standard Library? E.g. would a bitmap or an array or linked list take the least amount of resources to traverse and modify?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but a bit vector or a bit set / bit array may be what you need?

Comment: I'll make a quick clarification in the question.

Comment: So bit manipulation would be the fastest, least resource consuming technique?

Comment: It depends on how you want to identify each boolean. If they have consecutive indexes then a simple bit array is easiest and fastest

Comment: Well, there's all the other things.. Do you need to track ownership?   Can you store memory-management data in the free areas?

Comment: This is just for physical page frames. I intend on using page tables and page directory to keep track of ownership. And to answer your last question, yes.

Comment: You might want to look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372515/how-to-implement-a-bitset-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many filesystems have the same problem:  indicating whether an allocation unit (group of disk sectors) are available or not.  Except for MSDOS's FAT, I think all use a [bitmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap).  Definitely NTFS and Linux's ext/ext2/ext3/ext4 use bitmaps.

There are several easy optimizations to make.  If more than 8/16/32/64 sequential units are needed for an allocation, checking that many bits at once is simple using the corresponding integer size.  If a bit being zero means "available", then testing for a zero integer tells whether the whole allocation is available.  However, boundary optimizations might need to be considered.